# How to know the program that's dumping the core?

Tags: linux, process, core

I am seeing cores dumped in a particular directory continuously. I am sure there must a script that's continuously starting a process which is core-dumping and dying. But, how can I find which process is it?

Comment: What does the `file` command show you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger to look at the core file:

```
gdb --core=FILE
```

It should tell you what caused the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You should also find that the kernel logs the name and PID of the process that faulted.

Comment: It should be noted that this is only possible if you enabled the relevant option in the kernel. Some kernels come with this by default, others require that you compile it in.